# How to use TargetNullValue in Windows Phone 8?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I want to assign a place holder, if binding value is null. the answer is `TargetNullValue`, but I don't know how to use it practically!

here it says `ImageSource` is not valid:

```
<Image>
    <Image.Source>
        <Binding Path="ImageUri" >
            <Binding.TargetNullValue>
                <ImageSource>/Assets/PlaceHolder.png</ImageSource>
            </Binding.TargetNullValue>
        </Binding>
    </Image.Source>
</Image>
```

Comment: or you can write it like this: `<Image Source="{Binding Path=ImageUri , TargetNullValue='/Assets/PlaceHolder.png' , FallBackValue='/Assets/Placeholder.png'}">`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I had once a similar problem and solved it like this

```
<Image Source="{Binding Path=ImageUri, TargetNullValue='/Assets/PlaceHolder.png'}" />
```